# Get diff between two MongoDB documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to implement a 'homemade' **changelog** for my database in MongoDB.

My main objective is to be able to get the **difference between a document BEFORE and AFTER it is saved**, to get what attributes were changed, and log these changes in a new collection in the DB.

For example:

If I update the name of a person that's already in my database (let's say we update it *from: Michele* *to: Michelle*, I want to be able to get this change and add to my custom log: ***name changed***.

Is there anything that comes to your mind on how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

*PD: I'm currently using mongoose with node.js.*

Comment: multiple mongoose plugins available that can track `diff`  of objectw but none of them are maintained correctly (seems), search `diff` [here](https://plugins.mongoosejs.io/) to get those list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But do you know anything about $setDifference? May that help me out here if I have the document before it was saved and after it was saved?

Comment: no its for comparing 2 sets (array of unique items) in a document. it has nothing to do with tracking Documents. see example in Behavior section [$setDifference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#behavior)

Comment: alternatively you can use mongoose's [Doc.isModified](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified) to detect changes,

Comment: You can possibly use Change Streams to track the changes in documents in a collection. The Update Change Event document of the Change Stream Response shows the fields that are updated.